# Is is possible to edit an individual Widget in the QtDesginer?

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qt5.4, qlayout

I got a external library, which includes a derived class from QGLWidget, very similar to that one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517566/qt-mousereleaseevent-not-trigggered). In that library I have a class:

```
class PictureGLWidget : public QGLWidget { //.. }
```

This extends Qt's native QGLWidget and personalizes it. But it was not written by me, I just got it, via a *.dll. So then, I bind that Widget manually in my code to a layout like:

```
QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout;
layout->addWidget(myPictureGLWidget, 0, 1);
ui->verticalLayout_5->addLayout(layout);
```

since I designed my MainWindowWidget with the integrated QtDesigner, which is by the way very comfortable, I would like to handle my myPictureGLWidget also in the QtDesigner, since I am currently redesigning the MainWindow.

Is there a way doing that? Thnx in advance!

Comment: surely you used designer to create this widget you are adding

Comment: @AngryDuck No, the Widget I am adding, was not written by me. I got it as a *.dll.

Comment: a widget as a dll... i assume you mean you using a library that contains a widget which is what your are getting an instance of in your code then adding to your layout... if this is the case then i have no idea how you would get it into designer, i have done this with my own lib stuff but that needed compiling in VS2012 and then importing as a qt designer plugin i assume the lib your using wont have it compiled in a way that designer plugins will understand though :/

Comment: @Angryduck Exactly :( When I would have the source code, just (*.cpp & *.h) without any QtDesginer *.ui , would I be able to use it the QtDesigner then?

Comment: if the entire ui is just created in code from a cpp and a h file then i certainly wouldnt know how to open in designer my instinct is that it cant be done but dont take my work for it, why not just edit it in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt Designer supports any foreign widget class without needing to provide plugins for that. You only have to accept that the widget's properties and appearance won't be available within Designer.

1. Insert a dummy `QWidget` into the layout.
2. Right click on the widget, select "Promote to...".
3. Add `PictureGLWidget` as a new class promoted from `QWidget`. Specify appropriate header files etc.
4. Promote your widget to `PictureGLWidget`.

When this is done, the code generated by `uic` will instantiate a `PictureGLWidget` where you need it, instead of a dummy `QWidget`.

If you want to use the `PictureGLWidget` in the designer instead of a dummy widget, you can write a designer plugin that wraps the widget and exposes it in the widget pallette, provides property support, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question but don't you just add a QGLWidget to your design in Designer. Right click the widget and select Promote to... ?

Comment: I think he wants to edit contents of said widget. Promoting doesn't allow that

Comment: Well from the code sample it looks like he only wanted to get the widget in a layout and a promoted QGLWidget would definitely allow that...

Comment: I agree with you mikag.